# Can an ExpandoObject be a list?

Tags: c#, json, json.net, dynamic-language-runtime, expandoobject

I am using Json.Net to deserialize json results into `ExpandoObjects` using code like the following:

```
    var converter = new ExpandoObjectConverter();

    dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json, converter);
```

This works great for everything except responses that have only a list at the root of the json schema such as this:

```
string json = @"[{""title"": ""the title""}]";
```

In the bowels of `JsonConvert` is this method:

```
public static T DeserializeObject<T>(string value, params JsonConverter[] converters)
{
    return (T)DeserializeObject(value, typeof(T), converters);
}
```

The return value `DeserializeObject` is a properly constructed `List<object>` with on `ExpandoObject` in it but the code fails trying to cast that list to an ExpandoObject itself (the value of T).

I've got a failing unit test and could fix this but am not sure how to stuff a `List` directly into an `ExpandoObject`.

Is this possible? `DynamicObject` has [`TryGetIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so I assume an `ExpandoObject` can have an indexer. Would it be necessary to carefully construct a list-like instance of expando by dynamically supplying the implementation of an indexing method or otherwise create a non-expando `DynamicObject` to hold the list and invoke the correctly methods from dynamic method calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> DynamicObject has TryGetIndex so I assume an ExpandoObject can have an indexer

No, it can't. Just try it, it returns a `RuntimeBinderException`:

> Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject'

An `ExpandoObject` is not a list; it's more like a dictionary.

> Would it be necessary to carefully construct a list-like instance of expando by dynamically supplying the implementation of an indexing method or otherwise create a non-expando DynamicObject to hold the list and invoke the correctly methods from dynamic method calls?

Well, you could create a custom `DynamicObject` that behaves like a list, but I don't see any benefit in doing that: you might as well use a normal list.

Comment: I'm experimenting with a rest client that always returns dynamic objects. Only the outermost consumer code would know a list is expected if you know what I mean. So I'd have one code path for lists (client.GetList()) and another code path for everything else (client.Get()). Not the worst thing in the world I suppose. Json.Net's JObject can be a List but I am trying to avoid it as it has some other behaviors I'm not a fan of.

Comment: And you were right. I needed to give JSonConvert the hint which is what I was missing:

if (content.StartsWith("[")) 
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(content, converter);

return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(content, converter);